# How do I set Cache-Control metadata on a uniform bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-console

I have a bucket of images on Google Cloud storage. I've set the bucket's access control to uniform and made the bucket public. I'd now like to set the `Cache-Control` metadata for the bucket to have a `max-age` of one year, rather than the default one hour.

However, I cannot set the metadata for individual objects, since this is a uniform bucket. I simply get

`AccessDeniedException: 403 <my email> does not have storage.objects.update access to the Google Cloud Storage object.`

Which is expected.

I cannot find an option in the GUI or a command for the cloud shell to set metadata on a uniform bucket, does any one know how, or do I need to switch back to Fine-grained access control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you have is not related to setting object/s metadata! it means the `identity` (`google account` or the `service-account`) that you are using does not have permission to update objects in `buckets`.

You need to review the IAM permissions given to your `identity` and add all required IAM permissions.

---

You can edit the `Cache-Control` in object/s metadata from `Cloud Console` as follows:

> 1. In the Google Cloud Console, go to the Cloud Storage Browser page.
> 2. In the list of buckets, click on the name of the bucket that contains the desired object.
> 3. The Bucket details page opens, with the Objects tab selected.
> 4. Navigate to the object, which may be located in a folder.
> 5. Certain object metadata values, such as the object's size and storage class, are displayed along with the object's name.
> 6. Click the more actions menu ([image]) associated with the object.
> 7. Click Edit metadata.
>
>    The overlay window that appears shows the current values for the
>    object's editable metadata.

---

Reference: [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata).

Note:

> The Cloud Console does not provide an exhaustive list of metadata
> associated with objects. To view all of an object's metadata, follow
> the gsutil instructions.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I assumed uniform access control meant that ALL object settings were uniform, but I guess that only applies to public / private access, not metadata.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton You're welcome. `uniform` or `fine-grained` is not related to objects meta data. these are the two available types of GCS bucket access. either control access for the whole bucket (uniform) or control access per object (fine-grained).